# How do I specify different (PMD, Checkstyle, Findbugs) rulesets for test and production code using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I am Building a Java project with Gradle. I would like to separate tasks:

I would like to use strict rules (i.e. PMD, Checkstyle, Findbugs) for production code 
as well as more relaxed rules (i.e. allowing duplicate Strings and magic numbers) for tests .

I have done this previously with ant (quite simple), and even though I know I could just call the ant tasks from Gradle, I would rather use the respective plugins.

How do I go about this?

my current build script for PMD is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'
pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
    ruleSetFiles = files("$staticAnalysisCfgDir/pmd/pmdruleset.xml")
    toolVersion = '5.1.3'
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main, sourceSets.test]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of configuring rule sets on the `pmd` extension, configure them on the `pmdMain` and `pmdTest` tasks (same syntax). Likewise for Checkstyle and FindBugs.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question but it did not work. Now I tried again without specifying `sourceSets` =>it works!

Comment: `sourceSets` is only available on the `pmd` extension. It effectively determines which of `pmdMain`, `pmdTest`, etc. will be run as part of `gradle build`. For API details, check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).